# In VB.NET how do I tell my constructor that the current object init has failed

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom class with constructor, the class is setup such that it would legitly fail to init in some conditions.  How do I return nothing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return anything from a constructor, it's there to initialize.

There are a couple of things you could do, depending on the situation:

1. If the failiure to initialize is an exceptional circumstance, throw an exception and catch it using a `Try` block:

   ```
   Public Sub New()
       '... fail to initialize
       Throw New ApplicationException("Some problem") 'Or whatever type of exception is appropriate
   End Sub
   ```
2. If it fails a lot and you can't filter input or anything, make the constructor `Private` and construct in a `Shared` method:

   ```
   Public Shared Function CreateMyObject()
       If someFailure Then
           Return Nothing
       End If

       Return New MyObject() 'Or something
   End Function
   ```

Comment: I'll go with the throw approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old school but you could have a LastException Property that is set an exception is handled:

```
Public Class Foo
    Private _LastException As Exception = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property LastException As Exception
        Get
            Return _LastException
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Try
            'init
        Catch ex As Exception
            _LastException = ex
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This would require you to check LastException after class creation but it is an option?

Usage:

```
    Dim foo1 As New Foo
    If Not foo1.LastException Is Nothing Then
        'some error occurred
    Else
        'carry on
    End If
```